# Remove border from JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, border, jscrollpane

I have a `JList` object in a `JScrollPane` and the `JScrollPane` is inside of `JPanel`.

```
JList membersList = new JList();

JPanel membersPanel = new JPanel();
membersPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(membersList);

membersPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I tried to set the borders of membersList, membersPanel and scrollPane to null. I also tried:

```
Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);
membersList.setBorder(emptyBorder);
membersPanel.setBorder(emptyBorder);
scrollPane.setBorder(emptyBorder);
```

But somehow I can't remove the border. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks fine for me.  What Look and Feel are you using?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

The scroll pane has a viewport which can have its own border.

```
scrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);
```

Comment: So, I've been through Windows L&F, Nimbus and Metal and `scrollPane.getViewport().getBorder()` returns `null`?

Comment: At my job we use the Motif L&F (it's ancient, do not recommend). We have these `setViewportBorder(null)` calls sprinkled in various places.